# After Upgrade TYPO3 6.X to 7.6.18 'Fluid Content type' is empty

Tags: typo3

[image]

After Upgrade TYPO3 6.X to 7.6.18 'Fluid Content type' is empty.
I have already added **Content** elements on path 'typo3conf/ext/some_extension/Resources/Private/Templates/Content'.

Also content files are with Capitalize letter but still is not showing on 'Fluid Content type' dropdown. Any one have faced this kind of stuff?

Answer (score 0):

I find solution.

```
// ext_localconf.php
\FluidTYPO3\Flux\Core::registerProviderExtensionKey('myextensionkey', 'Content');
\FluidTYPO3\Flux\Core::registerProviderExtensionKey('myextensionkey', 'Page');
```

It's work for me.